# Finding a Recurrence Relation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

This is from AMC 2015 . 
For each positive integer n, let S(n) be the number of sequences of length n consisting solely of the letters A and B, with no more than three As in a row and no more than three Bs in a row.

I want to find out a recurrence relation for S(n).  I am not able to get it after many tries. I guess its not a simple one.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Hint: let $C(n)$ be the number of such sequences that start with $A$, similarly, $D(n)$ is the number of sequences that start with $B$.  Observe that $S(n)=C(n)+D(n)$.

Comment: One curiosity question: does the problem say 'find a recurrence for $S(n)$' or does it ask you to find a formula for $S(n)$?

Comment: Hint: Calculate number of not allowed sequences in a sequence of length $n$.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki the problem asks for the remainder when S(2015) is divided by 12

Comment: @Sudhanshu Ahhh, I see.  You can certainly build the recurrence relation, but you _may_ be able to argue by symmetry and get an answer very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

A hint: let $A_1(n)$, $A_2(n)$, and $A_3(n)$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ that end with exactly one, two, and three $A$s respectively, and similarly $B_1(n)$, $B_2(n)$, $B_3(n)$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ that end with exactly one, two, and three $B$s.  Then, for instance, $A_2(n+1)=A_1(n)$; a sequence that ends with exactly two $A$s is gotten by appending an $A$ to a sequence that ends with exactly one $A$.  You should find most of the recurrence relations trivial; the tricky ones are for $A_1$ and $B_1$.  How can you get a sequence with exactly one $A$ at the end of it?

Comment: I tried writing A1(n) in terms of other smaller A1's but the resultant series was too large. How to simplify?

Comment: @Sudhanshu What do you mean by 'too large'?

Comment: I meant that it had a lot of a1's and I was not getting a method to simplify it in terms of S(n-1) and such..

Comment: @Sudhanshu You won't get a direct recurrence relation for $S()$; rather, you'll get (entwined) recurrence relations for $A$ and $B$ - but that's not too complicated, since in fact there's a very obvious relation (what?) between $A_i(n)$ and $B_i(n)$.

Comment: Isn't A1(n+1)= B1(n) + B2(n) +B3(n) = B1(n) +B1(n-1) +B1(n-2)

Comment: @Sudhanshu That looks right to me.  But it's also true that $A_i(n)=B_i(n)$ for all $i$ : swapping all instances of $A$ and $B$ in a string in one class converts it to a string in the other class.